# The for attribute of the label element must refer to a form control

Tags: forms, css, label

I keep getting the above error on two of my lines of label code. I haven't been able to come up with a valid solution. Any takers would be of great help.

```
<input type="radio" name="payment_method" value="Bill Me">
<label div id="payment1" for="payment_method">Bill Me</label>
```

and

```
<input type="radio" name="payment_method" value="Bill Me">
<label div id="payment2" for="payment_method">Credit Card</label>
```

Comment: what's the `div` doing inside the `<label>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `for` attribute should correspond with an **ID** of a form control, not a name.

Give the input's a unique `ID` and use it as the value on each label's `for`, example:

```
<input name="payment_method" value="Bill Me" id="payment_method_bill">
<label id="payment1" for="payment_method_bill">Bill Me</label>
```

**FYI:** You have `div` before each label's ID, which is invalid and should be removed.

Comment: Oh thanks for reminding me about the div..they weren't meant to be there I was kind of playing around and forgot to delete them.